# Using roles in Asp.Net MemeberShip?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Well, the question is simple.

how can i use the roles in asp.net memebership,

i know i can do something like that :

```
<authorization>
<allow roles="Admin"/> //Allows users in Admin role

<deny users="*"/> // deny everyone else
</authorization>

</system.web>
</location>
```

but, where can i say user 'admin' is Role : Admin..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a tip of the ice berg. You need ASP.Net Membership and Role Providers, and configure few settings. You can implement your own providers, but it is easier to use the default ones.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SQL-Membership.aspx

http://odetocode.com/articles/427.aspx

```
<system.web>

    <membership>
        <providers>
            <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
            <add applicationName="YOURAPPNAME" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
        <providers>
            <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
            <add applicationName="YOURAPPNAME" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnectionString" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>

</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have RoleProvider
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx

If you are using Windows Authentication, the roles will be your AD groups.

If you are using Form Authentication, you can implement your own RoleProvider or use SQL Role Provider.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx