# ASP.NET: How can I create a Login System using aspnet_regsql.exe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles, asp.net-profiles

I want to create a login system using `aspnet_regsql.exe`

After the `aspnet_regsql.exe` installiation in my `SQL Server`, then what should I do next?

Can someone explain me step by step after the `aspnet_regsql.exe` installiation ?

Comment: Here are some answers too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526239/using-roles-in-asp-net-memebership/6527162#6527162

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is a bit too much to write here, but you will find an excellent series of articles here
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a site that explains asp .net authentication - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETauthentication.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

After installing aspnet tables on your database goto your web.config file
 `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UserConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="User Id = sa; Password=sqlserver2008; Initial Catalog=UserDATABASE; Data Source = DATA_NET_139\SQLEXPRESS; "/>
  </connectionStrings>`

In the Membership section add these lines

`<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="UserConnectionString" applicationName="SampleApplication"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="UserConnectionString" applicationName="SampleApplication"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="UserConnectionString" applicationName="SampleApplication"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>`

After this just drag a CreateUserWizar Control to your aspx page and use it. You do not have to write any code for inserting data in to the database asp.net do it automatically.

`<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>`

Only change the database name.